# Neo4j entity relationship diagram

Tags: neo4j

How to extract an entity relationship diagram from a graph database? I have all the required files that was created from my application.

Comment: Are you searching `CALL db.schema()` ?

Comment: Not exactly. Need to extract ER diagram like other RDBMS with all relationships in tabular format

Comment: But you are working with a graph data model... There no tables to extract from it. I'm right?

Comment: Right but as per requirement i need to extract data model & relationships with dataset

Answer (score 2):

You can use

`call db.schema` for a graph representation of the graph data model. There are a few other functions to get the properties, keys, indexes, etc like `call db.indexes, call db.propertykeys` etc.

The APOC procedure library has a few relevant functions that might help to get a tabular layout - or develop it yourself in Excel from the labels, property keys, etc.

You can also build a data model using [the Arrows tool](http://apcjones.com/arrows/#)

Please reorient your thinking to use graph terms - the equivalent for the ER diagram would be a model built using the Arrows tool or the db.schema.

Answer (score 1):

I used: `CALL db.schema.visualization` for visualizing the database schema. Like https://stackoverflow.com/a/45357049/7924573 already said, in graph databases this is as closest as you can to ER-diagrams. In the remote interface you can export it directly as  e.g. .svg graphic

Here is an example:[image]